# Why read.table cannot recognize tab separated header accurately in R

Tags: r, read.table

I have the following [data](http://dpaste.com/1487049/plain/)

```
GOBPID  Term    ADX_KD_06.ip    ADX_KD_24.ip    ADX_LG_06.ip (more columns)
GO:0000003  reproduction    0   0   0
GO:0000165  MAPK cascade    0   0   0
(more rows)
```

When I read it like the following

```
d1 <- read.table("http://dpaste.com/1487049/plain/",sep="\t",header=TRUE)
```

I expect `d1$GOBPID` to contain values like `GO:0000003`, but it access `Term` column
instead.

```
> d1$GOBPID
[1] reproduction   MAPK cascade ....
```

Basically, it doesn't assign the header column as it should.
Why is that? What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How big are your actual data?

As Richie Cotton pointed out, `count.fields` is useful for identifying how many delimiters there are in each row of your data. In this case, however, it was a little more useful to open the file up in a decent text editor that shows tab characters, and you would see that every line except for the first has a trailing tab. Because all the other rows have one more tab than the first, R assumes the first "column" should be the `row.names` which leads to the problem you're having.

Here are two possible options for this data:

***Option 1***

This is convenient if your data are small: Use `gsub` to get rid of the trailing tabs, and use `read.delim` on the output of that:

```
read.delim(text = gsub("\\t$", "", 
                       readLines("http://dpaste.com/1487049/plain/")))
```

***Option 2***

Read the table in skipping the first line, drop the last column (which should be all `NA` values), and add names by reading just the first line using `scan`:

```
out <- read.delim("http://dpaste.com/1487049/plain/", 
                  skip = 1, header = FALSE)
out <- out[-length(out)]
names(out) <- scan("http://dpaste.com/1487049/plain/", 
                   what="", n=length(out), sep = "\t")
```

Answer (score 2):

You may have space characters instead of tabs somewhere, or other malformed data.  Run

```
count.fields("http://dpaste.com/1487049/plain/", sep = "\t")
```

to see which lines are causing the problems.

Comment: Thanks. I still find it strange. Using `count.fields` gave me this:
`38 38 39 40 43 39 42 40 39 38`. Showing that the 3rd row is 39 fields instead of the correct 38. The only reason I can think of is the 3rd row it recognize `microtubule cytoskeleton organization` as 2 words. I tried `cut -f2` it correctly detects the column. But not `read.table()`.

Comment: @pdubois: Just updated my answer: you need to make the `sep` argument to `count.fields` the same as what you are passing to `read.table`.  (By default, any whitespace will be used as the separator.)